# PYTHON 3: Read a file and map the coordinates to the turtle screen

Tags: python, format, turtle-graphics

So I have to write a program that reads a `csv` file which contains earthquake data, it then takes only the latitude and longitude from the file and map it to the turtle screen in Python 3.

This is the [CSV file](http://textuploader.com/gayg)

My program:

```
import turtle
def drawQuakes():
 filename = input("Please enter the quake file: ")
 readfile = open(filename, "r")
 readlines = readfile.read()

 start = readlines.find("type")
 g = readlines[start]
 Type = g.split(",")
 tracy = turtle.Turtle()
 tracy.up()
 for points in Type:
     print(points)
     x = float(Type[1])
     y = float(Type[2])
     tracy.goto(x,y)
     tracy.write(".")
drawQuakes()
```

I know this program is fairly easy, but I keep getting this error:

```
x = float(Type[1])IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the file correctly, let's break it down:

```
readlines = readfile.read()
# readlines is now the entire file contents

start = readlines.find("type")
# start is now 80

g = readlines[start]
# g is now 't'

Type = g.split(",")
# Type is now ['t']

tracy = turtle.Turtle()
tracy.up()
for points in Type:
    print(points)
    # points is 't'

    x = float(Type[1])
    # IndexError: list index out of range

    y = float(Type[2])
    tracy.goto(x,y)
    tracy.write(".")
```

I would use the csv.DictReader:

```
import turtle
import csv

def drawQuakes():
    filename = input("Please enter the quake file: ")

    tracy = turtle.Turtle()
    tracy.up()

    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['type'] == 'earthquake':
                x = float(row['latitude'])
                y = float(row['longitude'])
                tracy.goto(x,y)
                tracy.write(".")

drawQuakes()
```

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: **Nothing happens on the screen for me** @DTing

Comment: I do not understand your program. Can you do it with my program? @DTing

Comment: Give me a min to update. I didn't notice you are only looking for earthquakes.